# Error with using Neo4j-spark-connector

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j

I have been following the example from https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-3-0-apache-spark-connector/ and everything seemed fine until I try the following assignment:
val query = "cypher runtime=compiled MATCH (n) where id(n) < {maxId} return id(n)"

I get the error "**Unable to connect to 'localhost' on port 7687, ensure the database is running and that there is a working network connection to it.**"
I am fairly new to Spark and am not sure how to fix this. When I ran this I had have my Neo4j database on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 7687 is the port for BOLT, the Binary protocol for Neo4j that the Java driver bundled in the Neo4j Spark Connector uses to pull data from Neo4j. So this is a connection error to Neo4j.

What version of Neo4j are you using? Are you using the default config settings for Neo4j?

Did you specify the password for neo4j as specified [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector#config):

```
spark.neo4j.bolt.password=<password>
```

If you're following the example from the blog post the command to start spark shell would look like this:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell \
--conf spark.neo4j.bolt.password=YOUR_PASSWORD_FOR_NEO4J_HERE \
--packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:1.0.0-RC1,\
graphframes:graphframes:0.1.0-spark1.6
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! The version of Neo4j I'm currently using is the 2.3.3 Community one. The exact code I tried is: `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell \
--conf spark.neo4j.bolt.password=MYPASSWORD\
--packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:1.0.0-RC1,\
graphframes:graphframes:0.1.0-spark1.6
import org.neo4j.spark._
Neo4jTupleRDD(sc,"MATCH (n) return id(n)",Seq.empty).count`
where Password is exactly my password and I still get the same connection error.

Comment: You'll need to use Neo4j 3.0. The spark connector uses the new official java driver over BOLT which was introduced in Neo4j version 3.0. It won't work with prior versions.

Comment: @WilliamLyon is there a data size upper limit for Neo4j Spark Connector ? For example Mazerunner persists all the data to an intermediate HDFS store... so theoretically it can work with hundreds of GB of data in batch mode. How will this connector work with say 100 GB of data ? we are looking to integrate a large neo4j db with spark.